# Show a function is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an odd function satisfying
$$ \forall x \neq 0, \quad 2f(x) +x \cos x = x + f(x)\sqrt{x^2 + 4}$$
Show that f is continuous at $0$.

---

I Know I need to show that $f(0)$ and  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ are equal and that it is $0$ at $f(0)$ beacause it is an odd function, but i am having trouble computing the limit.

I think I could do it by the sandwich theorem but I can't find the two equations for the sandwich.

Comment: Please write it properly .

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: An odd function is continuous iff its limit on the right in $0$ is $0$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$2f(x) +x\cos x = x + f(x)\sqrt{x^2 + 4}$$
then for every $x \neq 0$, one has $$f(x) = \dfrac{x - x \cos(x)}{2- \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}$$

Moreover, when $x$ tends to $0$ (with $x \neq 0$), one
has

$$x-x \cos(x) = x(1-\cos(x)) \sim  \dfrac{x^3}{2}$$

and $$2- \sqrt{x^2+4} = 2 \left[1- \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{x^2}{4}} \right] \sim - \dfrac{x^2}{4}$$

so $$f(x) \sim -2x$$

so $\displaystyle{\lim_{ x\rightarrow 0} f(x)= 0}$.
Finally, since $f$ is odd, then $f(0)=0$.

So you do have $$\displaystyle \lim_{ x\rightarrow 0} f(x)= f(0)$$

which means that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed

$$f(x) = \dfrac{x - x \cos(x)}{2- \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}$$

then by standard limit $\dfrac{1 -  \cos(x)}{x^2} \to\frac12$ we have

$$ \dfrac{x - x \cos(x)}{2- \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}=\dfrac{x(1 -  \cos(x))}{2- \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}\cdot \dfrac{2+ \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}{2+ \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}=$$

$$=-x\cdot\dfrac{1 -  \cos(x)}{x^2}\cdot(2+ \sqrt{x^2 + 4})\to0\cdot\frac12\cdot 4=0$$

therefore $f(x) \to f(0)$.